# Emergency Firmware Recovery

Tags: unbricking, recovery-mode

I tried a to update my samsung galaxy note with a new leaked operating system of jelly bean using odin3.
but at the time of adding files for phone and ccs i miss arranged them so the update got failed when i tried to reset the thing and upgrade it once again nothing would happen and then in my cell there is notification came that firmware upgrade encountered an issue.Please select recovery mode in kies and try again.
On conneting my cell phone to kies it wont detect my cell phone so i need an emergency firmaware recovery code so that i can recover my cellphone again.
please help